# Determine extrema of function

Tags: java, calculus

I'm running into an issue in which the minima is not being correctly set. The maxima is setting perfectly, but I know that the minima should be less than 0. Running this snippet, it seems like the minima is never being set. Any ideas?

edit: The curve points should be from -1 to 3. Here's an image:
[image: The curve]

```
public class FindingExtrema {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double lowestPoint = 0;
        double highestPoint = 0;
        double y;

        double x = -1;
        int timesCalculated = 0;

        while (x <= 3) {
            y = run(x);

            if (y < lowestPoint) {
                lowestPoint = y;
                System.out.printf("y: %1$.5f", y);
            }

            if (y > highestPoint) {
                highestPoint = y;
            }

            x += .00001;
            timesCalculated++;
        }

        System.out.println("Done!");
        System.out.printf("Lowest: %1$.5f, Highest: %2$.5f; Calculated %3$d times\n", lowestPoint, highestPoint, timesCalculated);
    }

    private static double run(double x) {
        return Math.cbrt(2 * x) - Math.sqrt(8 * x) + x + 16;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your function isn't defined for x < 0; Math.sqrt(8 * x) is imaginary.  Whatever function that is on Wolfram Alpha isn't the function you actually have in your Java code.

Comment: So how would I go about solving that? Just replace `Math.sqrt(8 * x) with 0?

Comment: You would go about solving that by writing the correct function in Java, because what you have here doesn't look at all like the graph you've provided.

Comment: That curve looks like a cubic to me. The formula should involve `Math.pow(..., 3)` and `Math.pow(..., 2)`, not `sqrt` and `cbrt`.

Comment: It should be `2 * x * x * x - 8 * x * x + x + 16`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington Perfect! Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.

Comment: @PaulBoddington, If you'd like to submit a solution I'd be glad to mark is as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
Math.cbrt(2 * x) - Math.sqrt(8 * x) + x + 16;
```

is not equivalent to the right hand side for the equation of your graph - you are getting cube root confused with cubing and square root confused with squaring.

The correct expression is

```
(2 * x * x * x) - (8 * x * x) + x + 16
```

Answer (score 2):

> but I know that the minima should be less than 0.

It isn't, if you graph it.  I plugged your function into Google for the range 0 to 3 and the minimum was something like 15.431.

Comment: If I set the default value of lowestPoint to 100, I do see that it's set to 15.xxxx, but that can't be right. -.-

Comment: @kneeki it's the right value for the function you've written in Java, but I don't think that's the function you wanted to write.

Answer (score 0):

Make your lowestPoint point as follows.

```
    double lowestPoint = 1000;
```

Could you please put the original equation? you can't find square root for minus value.

sqrt
public static double sqrt(double a)

Returns the correctly rounded positive square root of a double value. Special cases: ◦If the argument is NaN or less than zero, then the result is NaN. 
◦If the argument is positive infinity, then the result is positive infinity. 
◦If the argument is positive zero or negative zero, then the result is the same as the argument.
Otherwise, the result is the double value closest to the true mathematical square root of the argument value.Parameters:a - a value.Returns:the positive square root of a. If the argument is NaN or less than zero, the result is NaN.